# How to pass value for a variable with default value true or false or null in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, nullable, default-value

I have written below code in Kotlin for the different values of "isOlListingEnabled" as True, False and null. I got the comment on my PR as "Instead of making new method we can pass value for isOlListingEnabled in method *getFlightsOpinionLabModel* with default value true or false or null". Can someone please help me to write the below code in such a way that I can handle all three (true, false and null) values in same method.

```
package com.abc.api.flights.unit.fixture

import com.abc.api.flights.models.domain.TripType
import com.abc.api.flights.models.ui.opinionlab.FlightsOpinionLabModel
import java.util.UUID

object FlightsOpinionLabModelFixture {

    fun getFlightsOpinionLabModel(tripType: TripType): FlightsOpinionLabModel = FlightsOpinionLabModel(

        siteName = "www.abc.com",
        langId = 1033,
        duaid = UUID.randomUUID(),
        expId = null,
        tripType = tripType,
        isOlListingEnabled = true
    )

    fun getFlightsOpinionLabModelWithoutListingEnabled(tripType: TripType): FlightsOpinionLabModel = FlightsOpinionLabModel(

        siteName = "www.abc.com",
        langId = 1033,
        duaid = UUID.randomUUID(),
        expId = null,
        tripType = tripType,
        isOlListingEnabled = false
    )

    fun getFlightsOpinionLabModelWitListingEnabledNull(tripType: TripType): FlightsOpinionLabModel = FlightsOpinionLabModel(

        siteName = "www.abc.com",
        langId = 1033,
        duaid = UUID.randomUUID(),
        expId = null,
        tripType = tripType,
        isOlListingEnabled = null
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `FlightsOpinionLabModelFixture` can be simplified in such way:

```kotlin
object FlightsOpinionLabModelFixture {

    fun getFlightsOpinionLabModel(tripType: TripType, isOlListingEnabled: Boolean? = true): FlightsOpinionLabModel = FlightsOpinionLabModel(
        siteName = "www.abc.com",
        langId = 1033,
        duaid = UUID.randomUUID(),
        expId = null,
        tripType = tripType,
        isOlListingEnabled = isOlListingEnabled
    )
}
```

invokation example:

```kotlin
// FlightsOpinionLabModelFixture.getFlightsOpinionLabModelWithoutListingEnabled(type)
FlightsOpinionLabModelFixture.getFlightsOpinionLabModel(type, isOlListingEnabled = false)
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Tanana, but can we do something like isOlListingEnabled = true || false || null . How I can make it nullable.?

Comment: @Saurabh ah, sorry, I forgot about null. I've changed `getFlightsOpinionLabModel`. Now you can use `null` for `isOlListingEnabled`

Comment: If the object could be moved to the `companion object` for `FlightsOpinionLabModel`, then you could rename the method to [`operator fun invoke()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#invoke-operator), which could be called as `FlightsOpinionLabModel(…)` — looking just like a constructor call.  (Even better if the actual constructor had those defaults; then that would do everything you want and there'd be no need for a separate function anyway…)

Comment: Thanks again @Andrei Tanana. This served the purpose.